# How to add event listener to calendar Popup in Datebox in ZK?

Tags: javascript, zk

How to add event listener to calendar Popup in Datebox in ZK ?

```
Datebox dateBox = new Datebox(dateObject);
// now add event listener
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no server-side event for opening a datebox popup by default. Since opening a popup is a pure client-side action and no data changed. If you want to add a java listener, you can apply the attached js. That js will override databox widget to send an `onOpen` event to the server when  you click the calendar icon to open the popup. Then you can call

`dateBox.addEventListener("onOpen", new EventListener<Event>() {...});`

```js
zk.afterLoad('zul.db', function() {
    var exWidget = {};
    zk.override(zul.db.CalendarPop.prototype, exWidget, {
        open: function(silent){
            exWidget.open.apply(this, arguments);
            zAu.send(new zk.Event(this.parent, "onOpen", null, {toServer:true}));
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Hawk , can you please give same js for "onSelect" date in datebox calendar popup.

Comment: You can listen to `onChange` when users select a date. see [supported events](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Base_Components/InputElement#Supported_Events)